# Issues installing libsodium23

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, dpkg

Any ideas how to remedy this? I get this error when I try to run sudo apt-get -f install

```
Preparing to unpack .../libsodium23_1.0.16-0ppa3~xenial1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsodium23:amd64 (1.0.16-0ppa3~xenial1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsodium23_1.0.16-0ppa3~xenial1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.23.1.0', which is also in package libsodium18:amd64 1.0.16-0ppa1~xenial1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsodium23_1.0.16-0ppa3~xenial1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

With apt-cache policy libsodium*:

```
libsodium18:
  Installed: 1.0.16-0ppa1~xenial1
  Candidate: 1.0.16-0ppa1~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.16-0ppa1~xenial1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.8-5 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
libsodium23:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.16-0ppa3~xenial1
  Version table:
     1.0.16-0ppa3~xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phoerious/keepassxc/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libsodium-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.8-5
  Version table:
     1.0.8-5 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
libsodium-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.16-0ppa3~xenial1
  Version table:
     1.0.16-0ppa3~xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/phoerious/keepassxc/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.0.8-5 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1011495/edit) your question with output of `apt-cache policy libsodium*`.

Comment: I've just done that, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really use packages from [ppa:phoerious/keepassxc](https://launchpad.net/~phoerious/+archive/ubuntu/keepassxc)?

Comment: Yep, to keep my keepassxc updated.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, with `sudo apt-get install libsodium-dev`  I had a similar issue `The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libsodium-dev : Depends: libsodium23 (= 1.0.18-1) but 1.0.18-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed (..)`.  I resolved my issue with https://doc.libsodium.org/installation  ie 1)`wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18-stable.tar.gz` 2)`tar xvf libsodium-1.0.18-stable.tar.gz` 3)cd to the dir 4)`./configure` 5)`make && make check` 6)`sudo make install` 7) in R `install.packages("plumber")` =>R plumber 1.0.0 works !`

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out by follow instructions in [this link](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/1545#issuecomment-369163954):

```
apt install --reinstall libsodium18=1.0.8-5
```

Comment: Usually link-only answers are not good. Edited it to contain necessary information from link.